# Terminology: A Graph that isn't, strictly speaking

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Take a simple (but not necessarily the best) example: Draw four points in the plane and their nearest-neighbor graph. If you now move a point, the graph changes too, and it might do it not isomorphically to the old one!
Do you still speak of a "graph" in such cases, even if e.g. metric properties went into its construction? Of course *after* it was constructed, it can be analyzed with standard graph theory...

Comment: I think usually a graph (basic sense) is a pair $(V,E)$ with $V$ (vertices) a set of points, and $E\subset P(V)$ with the property that $x\in E \implies |x|=2$. So a set of points and and a collection of pairs which are the edges. (although maybe you want to rule out an empty graph etc.) The various visualisations/isomorphisms I suppose are just convenient but how you arrived at that particular construction/realisation doesn't impact whether it's a graph or not.

Comment: It sounds like you have something like a function from sets of four points in the plane to [finite graphs].

Comment: That's a function "points $\to$ graph".